# How to delete elements of a persisted map with jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, playframework

I am trying to delete an entity which contains a map of entities as follow:

```
@Entity
public class TrxReport extends Model {
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "StatCategory")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "TrxReport_key", nullable = false)
    @Cascade(value = { CascadeType.ALL })
    public Map<String, TrxStatCategory> categories;

    @Override
    public TrxReport delete(){
        for (AtmPosTrxStatCategory cat : categories.values()) {
            if (cat != null){
                categories.remove(cat.name);
                cat.delete();
            }
        }
        super.delete();
        return this;
    }
}
```

However I always get a constraint violation error complaining about categories_id on StatCategory table.
Does the delete need to be done with a custom query or can it be achieved as similar to above?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting the error because the categories you are trying to remove get removed twice because of the `CascadeType.ALL`. If you use `orphanRemoval` then the `TrxStatCategory` will also get deleted if they get removed from the `categories` collection  in `TrxReport`.

How about using `orphanRemoval`, without overriding `delete()`:

```
@Entity
public class TrxReport extends Model {

    @CollectionTable(name = "StatCategory")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "TrxReport_key", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Map<String, TrxStatCategory> categories;

}
```

Comment: I don't think a map of entities can be persisted using hte @OneToMany annotation

Comment: Have you tried using it with [@MapKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKey.html)?

Comment: Could you not make it a one-to-many, then have a seperate property that is readonly that does the map?